# Darboux and Riemann Sums

Tags: calculus, analysis, riemann-sum

Can someone explain to me the concepts of Darboux and Riemann Sums? I find it hard to understand the true meaning behind the mathematical notation.
For example, how can someone grasp this concept
$$f\colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R} \text{ is Riemann integrable iff }$$$$ (\forall \epsilon)( \epsilon > 0((\exists \delta) (\delta  > 0((\forall \Delta\text{ partition of the interval }[a, b])  \implies (\exists I \in \mathbb{R})(\lvert\lvert \Delta \rvert\rvert) \implies (\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n(f(\xi_i)(x_{i}-x_{i-1})) - I\rvert < \epsilon)))$$

Comment: Try to draw a picture based on the definition. You could also google for pictures, there are *a lot* of them

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) might be a better start than that monstrous mathematical notation.

Comment: you forgot to use $\delta$ in this expression ! it should be $\dots (\|\Delta\|<\delta) \dots$.

Comment: [Mandatory 3Blue1Brown Link](https://www.3blue1brown.com/topics/calculus). Specifically about integration is [here](https://www.3blue1brown.com/lessons/integration).